# Getting error when calling PayPal API in sandbox mode

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am new to PayPal integration coding and getting this error response by the PayPal API:

"10001 Internal Error"

..and here is what I had sent to paypal at "https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp":

> METHOD=DoExpressCheckoutPayment&TOKEN=XY-37X97072&PAYERID=B7JHY6QVBX&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=9.9&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale&USER=info_api1.abcd12345.com&PWD=YJHT2GXEL8H2L&SIGNATURE=NIXVrzp399rJ6uMui6ZfAxt&SUBJECT=NewOrder&VERSION=124.0&BUTTONSOURCE=PP-ECWizard

Can someone see what I am doing wrong and please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&SUBJECT=NewOrder` Get rid of this, that's not a valid payee recipient

---

Why are you using the very old Classic API instead of the current v2/checkout/orders?  See: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls

You'll need two routes on your server that return JSON, one for 'Create an Order' and one for 'Capture Order'.  Then pair those two routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: I used most of the code from an old projecct as I am a moderate level in csharp but I could follow the code and make changes. Taking out subject name/value did the trick and now my order processed. Would you or someone have a working code in csharp to use new  method? it would certainly be appreciated.